# How to Group result from mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, count

My Table:

```
datetime.                employment.        name
2019-11-25 12:32:12.     office.            Michael Jackson
2020-01-31 12:32:22.     production.        Jenny Darling
2019-12-25 12:32:12.     office.            Michael Jackson
etc.
```

This is a "time registering" table, so names must be DISTINCT for each mounth. (How many unique names is there every month grouped by month and employment)

Now i'd like to create a table that will show how many employees there was in every month by year.
So the table will look like:

```
Year & Month.    Employment.   Number (Unique names)
-------------------------------------
2019-01.         Office.       50
2019-01          Production.   35
2019-02.         Office.       45
2019-02.         Production.   36
```

And so on for this and prev year (2019 & 2020)

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table COUNT(DISTINCT(name)) AS number GROUP BY datetime AND employment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation... but your query is invalid in several regards. I think you want:

```
select
    date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m') yr_month,
    employment,
    count(distinct name) no_unique_names
from mytable
group by yr_month, employment
```

This gives you on row per year/month and `employment`, with the corresponding count of distinct `names`.

Comment: $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(usr_stamp_in, '%Y-%m') year_month, usr_employment, COUNT(DISTINCT usr_name) no_unique_names
                                                        FROM usr_time_reg
                                                        GROUP BY year_month, usr_employment";

Comment: Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month, usr_employment, COUNT(DISTINCT usr_name) no_unique_names ' at line 1

Comment: @BjörnC: my bad, `year_month` is a reserved word in MySQL. Fixed.

Comment: Np. Thank you. Changed and it works. Sometimes the reserved names are well hidden :)